# Hibernate+Spring transaction not updating properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm fairly new to using Hibernate+Spring, but after a while going through the docs I go the basics of it without too much problem.
I'm facing a problem that I couldn't find any information about, I think it's easier if I post an example to understand what I mean.

So I have this method to update a date field on UserTask:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
  @Override
  public Usertask startUserTask(Long usertaskID, Date start) 
  {
    Usertask ut = getCurrentSession().get(Usertask.class, usertaskID);

    String query_stm = "update " + Usertask.class.getName() + " ut set ut.userTaskActualStart = :actualstart where ut.userTaskID = :userTaskID";
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(query_stm);
    query.setParameter("actualstart", start);
    query.setParameter("userTaskID",usertaskID);
    query.executeUpdate();

    ut = getCurrentSession().get(Usertask.class, usertaskID);

    return ut;
  }
```

So first I get my Usertask entity from the database and I everything is ok with it. Then I use a query to update only the userTaskActualStart field on the database.
I was expecting that ut would also have the userTaskActualStart field updated to reflect this, but doesn't seem level 1 cache entities are updated when you do updates through queries?

I tried reading Usertask again from the database and I was expecting to see the userTaskActualStart filled this time, which doesn't happen as well. I know the transaction wasn't actually commited yet since it's within a method with a @Transactional annotation, but using regular JDBC it would work this way.

Is this the way things work with Hibernate? Is there any way to make it configurable so that within the same transaction I can actually see the previous updates?
This can be a bit annoying imo since you'll end up with your level 1 cache entities not synchronized with the database.

If I call:

```
utDao.startUserTask(userTaskID,new Date());
Usertask ut = utDao.get(Usertask.class, usertaskID);
```

Then the Usertask entity will come with the userTaskActualStart properly filled as it should since the transaction was already commited of course.

Any help I can get to understand these concepts a better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your level 1 cache only synchronizes with the database when a flush occurs. You can configure when this happens. Take a look at this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

Comment: Isn't this the other way around? Flushing synchronizes the database with the session state? If I call flush() my level 1 cache will remain the same (ie no updates), I will need to invoke get() again to synchronize it with the database.